# URL suggestion based on the 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I currently have a script that suggest a new url (valid) of my site when a user goes to a 404 page. The problem is that I have to manually add each suggested url that matches a common 404 page error.
For example if the user types `www.site.com/movie/the-lasst-movie` this should know it should be  `www.site.com/movie/the-lastest-movie`, which currently works if I add the url into the database. The problem is that there are a lot of pages and the process to add 1 by 1 into the db would be massively time wasting. 
The question is, is there a method to know a valid url (after getting into a 404 error page) that is the closest matching ?

PS: the current script uses `levenshtein` PHP function to compare a valid url (retrieved from db) with the current typed url (that generated 404 error page) and show the best matching url.

Comment: Why don't you process the 404 pages with a custom PHP page using .htaccess and dynamically generate those suggestions? You can add this rule to your .htaccess: ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php

Comment: @nikoskip Thanks for replying, I understand the aproach, but how could I know if the suggested url is valid? or how could I suggest a valid url against an invalid one.